# How to load a VAADIN Java web page using curl or anything else

Tags: java, curl, tomcat7, vaadin

For a VAADIN Java application, I created a class which is loaded when I go on the designed web page.

This class must be started each day at 12:00AM, so I wanted to create a bash script which uses curl to request the designed page to load the class and start everything.

The problem is, when I tried to get the page with curl using:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/Cub2dV725/mailengine
```

I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;chrome=1">
  <style type="text/css">html, body {height:100%;margin:0;}</style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/reindeer/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/reindeer/favicon.ico">
 </head>
 <body scroll="auto" class=" v-generated-body">
  <div id="Cub2DV725marketingmailengine-730874983" class=" v-app reindeer">
   <div class=" v-app-loading"></div>
   <noscript>
    You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.
   </noscript>
  </div>
  <iframe tabindex="-1" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0;overflow:hidden" src="javascript:false"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
if (!window.vaadin) alert("Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: .\/VAADIN\/vaadinBootstrap.js");
if (typeof window.__gwtStatsEvent != 'function') {
vaadin.gwtStatsEvents = [];
window.__gwtStatsEvent = function(event) {vaadin.gwtStatsEvents.push(event); return true;};
}
vaadin.initApplication("Cub2DV725marketingmailengine-730874983",{
    "heartbeatInterval": 300,
    "versionInfo": {
        "vaadinVersion": "7.2.5"
    },
    "vaadinDir": ".\/VAADIN\/",
    "authErrMsg": {
        "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC to continue.",
        "caption": "Authentication problem"
    },
    "widgetset": "com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet",
    "theme": "reindeer",
    "debug": true,
    "comErrMsg": {
        "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC to continue.",
        "caption": "Communication problem"
    },
    "standalone": true,
    "sessExpMsg": {
        "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC key to continue.",
        "caption": "Session Expired"
    }
});
//]]></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the class has not been loaded (I know because there is a system.out.print("loaded"); at the start of the class.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you happen find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org)

just created a script.js with this code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:8080/Cub2DV725/mailengine', function() {
        phantom.exit();
});
```

and a bash script:

Here, /var/lib/PhantomJs is where i extracted it

```
/var/lib/PhantomJs/bin/phantomjs /var/scripts/script.js
```

now i just need to add a crontab entry to start the script each day at 12:00AM

Comment: there is hardly more overkill that can be added

Comment: more overkill? i don't understand